# Only get sound notifications from contacts and certain apps

Tags: notifications, audio, do-not-disturb

I get a lot of annoying spam calls and texts. I want my phone to only give me a sound notification when someone from my contacts list calls or texts me. So I turned on the Do Not Disturb mode, and selected the priories, so that I only get notifications from my contacts.

The problem with this, is that now none of my apps give me notifications. I still want to get notifications from certain apps, like Skype for instance. So I clicked on the app notifications, to select the apps that I want to override the do not disturb. But I am only given a few odd app choices, not all of my apps. (See photo) But if I turn off do not disturb, I get spam calls and texts all day, which is pretty annoying.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can get sound notifications from my contacts only (Call and Text), but still get other app notifications?

I appreciate anyone's help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you have non-stock OS, like Samsung? I'm on a Pixel and (1) the "do not disturb" app menu lists all the apps and (2) there's also a menu called "display options for hidden notifications" that lets me select "no sound from notifications"

Comment: I don't think I have non-stock OS. I fixed the issue, with the answer below from svin83. But thanks for the comment. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Info

You could be better off with another approach like for example:

1. Set the notification sounds for SMS and ringtone to an empty audio clip. (no sound)
2. Add all your contacts to a contact group.
3. Set your preferred SMS/ringtone sounds for that entire contact-group.

This may be better for long term use since it won't hide and silence notifications of all installed apps.

Note: *This may depend on your phone make/model/firmware.*

### Answering your question

I'll use Skype as an example.

**Open app info for skype**
Settings->Apps->Skype

**Notification settings**
Select notifications, then tap *the name* of any *notification category* (not the toggle switch).

Then toggle (enable) the option named *Ignore do not disturb* at the bottom the list.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem!

Comment: Glad I could help you out.